# Git: checking efficiently that work tree, staging area, local repo and remote repo all match

Tags: git

I regularly work on the same set of git repos on multiple computers. Both at the beginning of a work session, and at the end of a work session, I run a script which will report if any of the git repos on the computer have "unstaged," "uncommitted," "unpushed" or "unpulled" contents. I guess using better git terminology I want to make sure that on that computer,

"work tree" = "staging area" = "local repo" = "remote repo",

Some time ago I parsed, from sources I can no longer remember, a script that seems to accomplish this task. In the script below, environment variable `GITS_DB` refers to a text file which contains one line for each directory containing a git repository.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # no color

for g in $(< ${GITS_DB})
do
    (
        cd ${g}
        git fetch --all &> /dev/null|| \
            echo "warning: unable to fetch ${g}, getting local status"
        if [ $(git status --porcelain | wc -l) != "0" \
            -o $(git rev-list HEAD@{upstream}..HEAD | wc -l) != "0" \
            -o $(git rev-list HEAD..HEAD@{upstream} | wc -l) != "0" ];  then
            echo -e "${RED}${g} is not clean${NC}"
        fi
    )
done
```

If the script reports that a repo is not clean, I `cd` into the repo and fix the issue. Fixing could mean commit, push or pull.

I have used this script for some time, and it seems to work. However, it is quite slow, even with a fast network connection. So

*Is there a faster (simpler) way to achieve what the script does?*

Edit. Deciphering the script with man pages, I wonder if the two `rev-list` commands could be replaced by comparing whether `HEAD` and `HEAD@{upstream}` have the same SHA-1 codes. That is, something like

```bash
$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD) != $(git rev-parse --verify HEAD@{upstream})
```

Edit 2 removed in favour of edit 3 below.

Edit 3. Here is the best attempt at the moment, including

- `fetch`es in parallel (by @Useless)
- `fetch -q` (by @RomainValeri)
- `rev-parse` by myself.

However, doing fetches in parallel is a bit tricky, since there are plenty of submodules. After doing some additional reading and experimenting, the two scripts below do the following:

- first script creates a file with one line for each repo; first character on line is 's' if the repo is a submodule, and 't' if it is not a submodule (is "top-level")
- second script 1. first fetches, one process for each top-level repo, and parallelization within each fetch for recursive submodules using config variable `submodule.fetchJobs` which seems to be passed recursively (while `--jobs` is not passed recursively) 2. then checks cleanliness of repos.

The running time of the first script is irrelevant. With these new versions, the running time of the actual cleanliness check is down from around 2 minutes (original) to 5-7 seconds.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# test that the var defining db location exists
if [[ -z "$GITS_DB" ]];
then
    echo "Environment variable GITS_DB has no value, exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

# create db directory if necessary
GITS_DIR=`dirname $GITS_DB`
mkdir -p ${GITS_DIR}

# remove old db if exists
if [ -e ${GITS_DB} ];
then
    rm ${GITS_DB}
fi

# create empty db file
touch ${GITS_DB}

# concatenate git directories into db, longest path first
for REPO_DOT_GIT in `find $HOME -name '.git' -printf "%d %p\n" | sort -nr | awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
    REPO_DIR=`dirname ${REPO_DOT_GIT}`
    (
        cd ${REPO_DIR}
        if [[ $(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree) ]];
        then
            REPO_TYPE=s # submodule
        else
            REPO_TYPE=t # top module
        fi
        printf "%c %s\n" "${REPO_TYPE}" "${REPO_DIR}" >> ${GITS_DB}
    )
done
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # no color

# fetch all toplevel repos (with submodules) in parallel
while read TYPE DIR;
do
    if [[ "${TYPE}" == "t" ]];
    then
        (
            cd ${DIR}
            # use parallelization when fetching submodules recursively
            git -c submodule.fetchJobs=20 fetch -q --all --recurse-submodules=yes ||
                {
                    echo -e "${RED}unable to fetch ${DIR} or its submodules, exiting${NC}";
                    exit 1
                }
        ) &
    fi
done < ${GITS_DB}
wait

while read TYPE DIR;
do
    (
        cd ${DIR}
        if [[ $(git status --porcelain) ||
             $(git rev-parse --verify HEAD) != $(git rev-parse --verify HEAD@{upstream}) ]];
        then
            echo -e "${RED}${DIR} is not clean${NC}"
        fi
    )
done < ${GITS_DB}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, why not just `fetch -q` rather than `fetch --all &> /dev/null`? The `-q` (or `--quiet`) option suppresses output. (and `--all` is implied by default, no need)

Comment: @RomainValeri Good point about `fetch -q`. My `man git-fetch` does not indicate that `--all` would be default.

Comment: When you say it's slow, do you actually think the `rev-list` part is slow? What does that have to do with the network? You could easily run all the fetches in parallel...

Comment: @Useless I have not profiled the script, so I do not actually know which parts are slow. I am also not sure which parts require network connection, except that `fetch` does and `status` probably does not. Indeed `fetch`es could be run in parallel, good idea. Handling all of the individual repos could not be run trivially in parallel, because the output is needed in specific order (in the order in which the repos are listed in `GITS_DB`).

Comment: @Useless Fetches in parallel made a *big* difference, see edit 2 in the original message. Thanks!

Comment: @jhu I have to thank you, for this comments echange cleared a bad assumption I was making for a long time. No, `--all` is *not* implied by default, `origin` is assumed if no remote is given in argument. My bad :-)

Comment: @Useless Eventually running fetches in parallel turned out to be the key, but I needed to do it at two levels: at shell level for toplevel repos with no interdependencies, and at git level for repo trees with submodules. See edit 3 above.